# Integração de Sistema C# Desktop com Sistema WEB em ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Estou com um Sistema Desktop em C# e os dados são gravados no SQLServer.
Como posso gravar esses dados simultaneamente em um Sistema WEB desenvolvido em ASP .NET ?

Comment: Esse sistema é uma API REST?

Comment: Não @dcastro, ado.net 3 camadas com duas class library

Comment: isso não tem nada a ver com o facto de ser uma API REST ou não. Ado é a framework usada para acesso à base de dados, e o facto de usar duas libraries é irrelevante. Eu estou a perguntar qual a interface pública desse projecto. É uma API ou são páginas web?

Comment: Desculpe a falta de conhecimento, são páginas web.

Comment: então nao tem maneira de integrar programaticamente. Precisas de expor o funcionamento atraves duma [API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Comment: Tem como através de uma webservice?

Comment: Sim, aquilo a que geralmente se chama um web service é uma API SOAP. SOAP está a cair em desuso, recomendo antes aquele link que postei no meu último comentário, mas qualquer um dos dois "funciona".

Comment: Nem todo webservice é uma api soap. Particularmente prefiro json pelo overhead menor. Mas cada caso é um caso e soap ainda é muito útil.